# Where will be my Grails default installation location?

Tags: software-installation

I installed Grails using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install grails-2.0
```

It installs and it works fine. Now where I can find my installation files?

Since I'm newbie to Ubuntu I couldn't able to guess where the installation file will be for Grails(and for other installations that are done via `sudo` commands).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dpkg -L grails-2.0` to list files from this package.

Also you can use `dpkg -S /file/name` to find out if the file belongs to any package.